# Get popular posts using Blogger API V3

Tags: google-blogger-api

How to get `Popular Posts` with `'All Time'|'LAST_YEAR'|'30 Days'|'7 Days'`  filter in Blogger API V3.

[image: popular posts configuration screen]

Can someone point me to the similar endpoint in Blogger API?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no endpoint available in Blogger API (https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/) which exposes the Popular Posts data for a blog. Google has acknowledged this and accepted it as a feature request (dating back to 2012) but till now no such public endpoint has been made available for the same.

> I don't believe we expose the popular pages for a blog in any of our APIs at this point. I'll take this as a feature request =)

Refer to https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bloggerdev/G1Ew5ezZOhU/VhReyn5NXO8J

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @Prayag do we have any other alternative to get this kind of information.

Comment: @little_big_thoughts You might want to look into services which generate RSS feeds out of websites elements (like Feedity, FetchRSS)